# jquery tooltip with dynamic content

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tooltip

I am trying to implement a jquery tooltip with dynamic content. So, the tooltip content is built in the callback function dynamically and changing depends on the form state.

My problem is that every time tooltip showed up, more HTML is added with tooltip content.

How to avoid adding this HTML to my document every time tooltip showed up ?

Thanks.

Comment: Add relevant code please.

Comment: I found the discussion about the same here:
https://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/10689?cversion=0&cnum_hist=2

Answer (score 0):

I found discussion about the same issue here. And there is a solution listed at the end.

https://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/10689?cversion=0&cnum_hist=2

```
$(".tooltip").each(function(idx, element) {
        // We cycle through the elements using each() so that we can choose the element specifically that we wish to clean up afterward
        var ele = $(element);
        ele.tooltip({
            "close": function(evt, ui) {
                // Only get rid of extraneous elements. We'll keep the one that was creted last.
                ele.data("ui-tooltip").liveRegion.children(":not(:last)").remove();
            }
        });
    });
```